# How can I bind to the last item in a list?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

While using XAML in WPF, we can easily bind to the first item in a list as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Persons[0].FullName}"/>
```

But what if I wanted to bind to the last item? Let's say I don't know how many items the list may have or else I could easily have used that index.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Persons.Last.FullName}"/>
```

or

Neither above does not work unfortunately. Does anyone have any idea how to bind to the last item?

Comment: There is no easy way to execute.
The easiest way is to set a property in the ViewModel, which will be in sync with the last item in the collection.
If this is not possible, then it will be possible to come up with implementation options in the View, but he will be more difficult to implement.

Comment: Ah so you are saying that while I can get a particular index using [x], there is no way for me to call the "Last" syntax?

Comment: You can try to set the index of the last element in different ways, including there is such a way `[^ 1]`.
But the problem is, Binding doesn't watch the index change.
It will be evaluated once at the time of Binding initialization and will then return the element at this previously calculated index.
Therefore, it is impossible to make simple binding.
But you can make a simple proxy in the logic of which the last element will be tracked.
And bind to this proxy.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a link where I could read more on the `[^1]`?

Comment: I'm asking because for now when I use `[^1]` I get the second item in the list only

Comment: This is syntactic sugar: `[^ 1]` is equivalent to `[Count -1]`.  
Calculated for the Count value at the time the binding was initialized.
If at the initial moment you had two elements in the collection, then then it will always return the second element.

Comment: You could bind to current of a collectionview using /. Icollectionview has a movecurrenttolast method.

Comment: Don't use any of the answers. You don't need a proxy or what ever. All you need is to implement `IValueConverter` and use the `Binding.Converter`, while binding to the source collection.

Comment: @BionicCode, if you can, show the implementation of such a converter so that it works correctly, including replacing the last item using the following code: `Collection [Collection.Count - 1] = newItem;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new property in your view model `LastItem` and bind to this property.

```
private Person lastItem;
public Person LastItem
{
    get { return lastItem; }
    set
    {
        lastItem= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Add a new line after the code where you load `Persons`:

```
...
LastItem = Persons.LastOrDefault();
...
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.LastItem.FullName}"/>
```

Comment: Yes correct but I was wondering if there was a "Last" syntax usable from xaml itself

Comment: This is a sensible way.

Comment: Added this as the most practical approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proxy code.
I wrote quickly, did not check - now there is not enough free time.
But the code is simple, there should be no errors.
If something doesn't work out, then write.
I'll try to fix it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace Proxy
{
    public class ProxyLastItem : Freezable
    {
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
            => new ProxyLastItem();


        /// <summary>Observable Collection: <see cref="INotifyCollectionChanged"/> or <see cref="IBindingList"/>.</summary>
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="ItemsSource"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ProxyLastItem), new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsSourceChanged));

        private static void ItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProxyLastItem proxyLast = (ProxyLastItem)d;

            IEnumerable collection = e.OldValue as IEnumerable;

            if (collection != null)
            {
                if (collection is INotifyCollectionChanged observableCollection)
                {
                    observableCollection.CollectionChanged -= proxyLast.OnCollectionChanged;
                    proxyLast.IsObservableCollection = false;
                }
                if (collection is IBindingList bindingList)
                {
                    bindingList.ListChanged -= proxyLast.OnListChanged;
                    proxyLast.IsBindingList = false;
                }

            }


            collection = e.NewValue as IEnumerable;
            if (collection == null)
            {
                proxyLast.LastItem = null;
            }
            else
            {
                proxyLast.SetLastItem(collection);
                if (collection is INotifyCollectionChanged observableCollection)
                {
                    observableCollection.CollectionChanged += proxyLast.OnCollectionChanged;
                    proxyLast.IsObservableCollection = true;
                }
                else if (collection is IBindingList bindingList)
                {
                    bindingList.ListChanged += proxyLast.OnListChanged;
                    proxyLast.IsBindingList = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetLastItem(IEnumerable collection)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(collection, ItemsSource))
                throw new Exception("The observable collection is not the same as the ItemsSource collection.");

            if (collection is IList list)
            {
                if (list.Count == 0)
                    LastItem = null;
                else
                    LastItem = list[list.Count - 1];
            }
            else
                LastItem = collection.Cast<object>().LastOrDefault();
        }

        private void OnListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
            => SetLastItem((IEnumerable)sender);

        private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            => SetLastItem((IEnumerable)sender);

        /// <summary><see cref="ItemsSource"/> is observable collection.</summary>
        public bool IsObservableCollection
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsObservableCollectionProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(IsObservableCollectionPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsObservableCollectionPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(IsObservableCollection), typeof(bool), typeof(ProxyLastItem), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> для свойства <see cref="IsObservableCollection"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsObservableCollectionProperty = IsObservableCollectionPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;



        /// <summary><see cref="ItemsSource"/> is BindingList.</summary>
        public bool IsBindingList
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBindingListProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(IsBindingListPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsBindingListPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(IsBindingList), typeof(bool), typeof(ProxyLastItem), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="IsBindingList"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBindingListProperty = IsBindingListPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        /// <summary>Last Item from <see cref="ItemsSource"/>.</summary>
        public object LastItem
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(LastItemProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(LastItemPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey LastItemPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(LastItem), typeof(object), typeof(ProxyLastItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="LastItem"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LastItemProperty = LastItemPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;


    }
}
```

Comment: That's too much. Simply implement `IValueConverter`.

Comment: Need a subscription to change the collection (CollectionChanged or ListChanged).
This cannot be done in the converter.
Or I don’t know about this method.
It is possible to create an IMultiValueConverter where one of the bindings will be for Count.
But it won't help if the last item is replaced by its index: `Collection [Collection.Count - 1] = newItem;`

Comment: You just have to raise PropertyChanged by setting the collection property or by raising the event explicitly after  modifying the source collection.

Comment: My solution can be used in a View regardless of the ViewModel implementation.
If you make changes to the ViewModel, then, as I immediately wrote in the first message, it is better to immediately add a property synchronized with the last element of the collection to the ViewModel.
It will be more efficient and easier than raising PropertyCanged and adding a converter.
@user2250152 showed the implementation of this in his answer.

Comment: In my opinion it adds too much complexity for a trivial problem. It's a nice idea, but way too complicated, too much lines of code. Check my answer. I found it to have less code and being more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to implement IValueConverter (see [Data conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0#data-conversion)).

**PersonsToLastPersonNameConverter.cs**

```
class PersonsToLastPersonNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => value is IEnumerable collection 
      ? collection
        .Cast<Person>()
        .LastOrDefault() 
        .FullName
      : Binding.DoNothing;

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <PersonsToLastPersonNameConverter x:Key="PersonsToLastPersonNameConverter " />
  </Window.Resources>

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Persons, Converter={StaticResource PersonsToLastPersonNameConverter}"/>
</Window>
```

**Model.cs**

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public List<Person> Persons { get; }

  public Model() => this.Persons = new List<Person>();

  private void AddItem(Person person)
  {
    this.Persons.Add(person);

    // Trigger the converter
    OnPersonsChanged();
  }

  private void RemoveItem(int index)
  {
    this.Persons.RemoveAt(index);

    // Trigger the converter
    OnPersonsChanged();
  }

  // Trigger the converter
  private void OnPersonsChanged() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Persons));

  // TODO::Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

Alternatively introduce a dedicated `LastPerson` property as binding source.

Comment: hmm great approach. I am going to give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

**If you** must import the Last Item from Xaml via Getter, try this method.
However, adding IValueConverter or Property is not as easy as adding it.

[image]

**And I put the sample source code.**

> [GitHub](https://github.com/devncore/stackoverflow-sample/tree/main/src/answers/binding-last-index)

*Using xaml*

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Users.FirstUser.Name}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Users.LastUser.Name}"/>
```

*Code*

```cs
public class UserItems : ObservableCollection<UserItem>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private UserItem _firstItem;
    private UserItem _userItem;

    public UserItem FirstUser
    {
        get { return _firstItem; }
        set { _firstItem = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public UserItem LastUser
    {
        get { return _userItem; }
        set { _userItem = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        FirstUser = this.FirstOrDefault();
        LastUser = this.LastOrDefault();
    }

    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

*ViewModel*

```cs
class MainViewModel
{
    public UserItems Users { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Users = new UserItems
        {
            new UserItem { Name = "James" },
            new UserItem { Name = "Elena" }
        };
    }
}
```